# Which format is more convenient to publish in Erdas Apollo?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, ecw, erdas-apollo

I am from Bolivia and I need to publish some Satellite images in Erdas Apollo. My question is Which format is more convenient for publish in this software?, because I have Landsat5 TM images in TIFF format and i'm watching the possibility to change or keep the format.

Answer (score 1):

Apollo can handle various image formats including geotiff, rrd, img, etc. If you already have your images in tiff format it makes sense to simply use that.